# jqGrid pager only displaying one page of results

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jqGrid displays correctly but it only shows one page of results. What ever I set rowNum to, that is all the results it will ever display even though right next to it it says it is displaying 10 out of 181 results. Is there some parameter I have to tweak to get the pager to allow me to actually page?

Thanks,
Kyle

```
  jQuery("#corporateavgmap").jqGrid({        
                        url:'monthly_corp_rates.jsp?'+dataString,
                        datatype: "json",
                        mtype:'POST',
                        colNames:['','USD', 'GBP', 'EUR','CAD','THB','HKD', 'MYR', 'JPY','AUD','IDR','KRW' ],
                        colModel:[
                            {name:'',index:'fromCurr', width:55, jsonmap:"fromCurr" },
                            {name:'USD', width:90, jsonmap:"toUSD"},
                            {name:'GBP', width:100, jsonmap:"toGBP"},
                            {name:'EUR', width:80, align:"right", jsonmap:"toEUR"},
                            {name:'CAD', width:80, align:"right", jsonmap:"toCAD"},
                            {name:'THB', width:80, align:"right", jsonmap:"toTHB"},
                            {name:'HKD', width:80, align:"right", jsonmap:"toHKD"},
                            {name:'MYR', width:80, align:"right", jsonmap:"toMYR"},
                            {name:'JPY', width:80, align:"right", jsonmap:"toJPY"},
                            {name:'AUD', width:80, align:"right", jsonmap:"toAUD"},
                            {name:'IDR', width:80, align:"right", jsonmap:"toIDR"},
                            {name:'KRW', width:80, align:"right", jsonmap:"toKRW"}

                        ],
                        rowNum:10,
                        rowList:[10,20,30],
                        pager: '#pjmap2avg',
                        sortname: 'tradeDT',
                        viewrecords: true,
                        sortorder: "desc",
                        jsonReader: {
                            root : "corporateavgrate",
                            repeatitems : false,
                            id: "fromCurr"
                        },
                        caption: "Average Corporate Rates For: "+month+"-"+year,
                        height: '100%',
                        reloadAfterEdit: true, 
                        reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                        reloadonce: false,
                        autowidth:true,
                        viewrecords: true,
                        gridview: true
                    });

                    alert("hello");

                    jQuery("#corporateavgmap").jqGrid('navGrid','#pjmap2avg',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,refresh:true}).
                    jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pjmap2avg",{caption:"Export to Excel",buttonicon:"", onClickButton: corpAVGMonthlyRatesTableToExcel , position:"last",title:"",cursor:"pointer"});
```

Comment: It sounds like your JSP isn't using the parameters to retrieve the appropriate set of data.

Comment: It retrieves the data just fine. It just doesn't display it all using pages. If I set rowNum to the size of the objects returned by my jsp everything is displayed in the grid.

Comment: jqGrid expects the server to return ONLY the page it asked for, not the entire table. It then displays the first `rowNum` entries from the returned data. It only does its own pagination when you use a local data source.